# MySQL get date of last month

Tags: mysql

I have this script which is run on the 15th of every month. This script intends to automatically take the last date of the previous month in the format of 'YYYY-MM-DD'. Is there a sql statement to do that?

For example today is 15th January 2017. I will run my script and it will give me a date of 31th December 2016 in the format 2016-12-31.

If it is 15th December 2016, I will get 30th November 2016 in the format 2016-11-30.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use curdate() - interval 1 month paired with last_day =)

```
select last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month) as 'last_day_last_month';
```

Comment: What if they don't have any records on last day of the month

Comment: Then their query will return 0 results based on the date that is returned; this may be legitimate. The query is dynamic and just returns a date to be used by another function.

Comment: @sumit What records? OP just asked how to calculate the last date of the previous month.

Comment: true .. I  was mistaken